# Centos 7 file system corrupted

Tags: centos, virtual-machine

I'm trying to restore my CentOS 7 virtual Machine as the file system got corrupted. This is the procedure I adopted for the same:

1. Unmount the file system using `umount /dev/mapper/centos00-root`
2. Tried `xfs_repair -n /dev/mapper/centos00-root`
3. Tried `xfs_repair /dev/mapper/centos00-root`.

Inspite of running the above 3 commands I was not able to restore my CentOS VM. I would request to please help me in restoring my VM.[image]

Comment: The program explains on the screen (shown in your screenshot) what you should do next. Why are you asking here?

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to mount the device, just do it and then check the XFS with `xfs_check`.

If mount is not possible, try to `xfs_repair -vL` *(but `-L` can be destructive, VM snapshot recommended)*.

Optionally you can try to debud the FS with `xfs_db` but everything can be destructive, so take snapshots.

Hope it helps.